# Decimal mark in a filename

Tags: standards, filenames

Is there a canonical way to write decimal marks in a filename? Dots, commas and apostrophe symbols are problematic.

Forgive me if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find anything similar. Maybe I didn't know how to look for it.

Comment: Which OS are you running? Different systems have varying rules for allowed chars in a filename. You can use as many "."'s as you want in a filename, but the last one is reserved for the filename extension. You could write a file named "12345.67.num", for example. I don't know what are you trying to reach by putting decimal numbers in a filename, but in UNIXes systems, you could even drop the .num if you want. Take a look at the [Filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename) entry on Wikipedia for more information.

Comment: I'm generating lots of files from acquired data, and they need to be sorted according to some parameters present in the filename.

Comment: If the purpose is sorting, you could define a fixed length name and fill it with zeros. You could drop the decimal mark in this case. For example: 000000001, 000000002 .... 000999999

Comment: It would help if you edit the question to be more specific and give some code example. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorted by what? The "ls" command? Windows Explorer? Your own code?

Comment: If you are not using the operating system interface, you want to show own interface files, file names, you can convert it to a binary string where the lists on the screen. only suggestion..
for example: "Brown's file\yes.txt"  bit binary 223i3f3n3e173j1036393c353p353j1e3k3o3k
//toString(32)

Comment: My case is not relevant to the question. I already had my own way to write decimal marks, but I was wondering if there was a standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Windows (7; probably relevant to later versions)**
Through experimentation I have discovered that you can name files with "." in them as long as the file extension is after the last ".". For example: 
".qerg..docx" is an acceptable file name, while "..rwhg..docx." is not.
Here I have a picture of a .txt file I named "...":

[image: screenshot]

**Macintosh OS 9**
Decimals are allowed, however colons (":") are not.
**Macintosh OS X**
Same rule as Mac OS 9, however file or folder names are not allowed to begin with a decimal.

**Unix**
The characters not allowed in Unix file and folder names are slash ("/") and NUL ("\0"), however in most Unix shells these characters (\ ? * | " < >) need to be escaped with a backslash, for example:
The file name:

```
What is > life?
```

Would need to be entered into the shell as:

```
What\ is\ \>\ life\?
```

*Further reading:*
There is a helpful Wikipedia article about your question [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words)

Answer (score 1):

Either put the filename in quotes:

```
$file="abc.def"
```

Or use an escape character ( which varies with OS )

```
copy data.txt to qwe\.rty
```